Github Actions: Array String as an input from a env variable
I am using docker/build-push-action@v5 and need to pass build-contexts from variable. Its type is List of strings: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action?tab=readme-ov-file#inputs
If I specify input directly like:
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
  with:
    build-contexts: |
      a=10
      b=20

It works fine. But the problems begin, when I try to use variable that has newlines:
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
  with:
    # Here we try to pass same thing, but just from a variable.
    build-contexts: |
      ${{ inputs.build_context }}

I use composite action to generate build-contexts value, which would be a string "a=10\nb=20". It is saved to environment variable, like:
    with open(os.environ["GITHUB_OUTPUT"], "a") as f:
        print(f"build_contexts={contexts}", file=f)

If I save "a=10\nb=20" value, then multiline string is stripped and only a=10 is preserved. If I escape \n, like "a=10\\nb=20", then whole string is preserved, but then docker build command does not recognize newline and uses it as a single context.
It tries to use build context like:
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --build-context a=10\nb=20

When expectation is to run like:
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --build-context a=10 --build-context b=20


Did you try saving it as a multiline string?

@Azeem I wonder how would I do that via python script?

By writing the first and the last line as in the docs with newlines e.g. print(f"build_contexts<<EOF\n", file=f), print(f"{build_contexts}\n", file=f), and print(f"EOF\n", file=f) (not tested). That should do it.

@Azeem looks like its working. I was also able to solve it using bash. But with python its more compact:). You can post this as an answer as well if you want
